# Supporting multiple Install receivers in android application

Tags: google-analytics, broadcastreceiver

We had a requirement to support multiple Install receiver in my Android using the following code

```
<receiver android:name="com.google.android.apps.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
      android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
      </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

But since the INSTALL_REFERRER can be received by only one receiver within the application we a were not able to get the install referrer in other BroadcastReceivers.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. MUltiple Install Receivers aren't supported. But there is a way out.

This article explains how it can be done -> https://mixpanel.com/help/questions/articles/how-can-i-use-multiple-install-trackers-with-the-android-library

Answer (score 0):

You can add your receiver classes in manifest as metadata. See the below code.

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.android.InstallReferrerReceiver" android:exported="true">
 <intent-filter>
   <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
 </intent-filter>
 <meta-data android:name="Receiver1" android:value="com.example.Receiver1"/>
 <meta-data android:name="Receiver2" android:value="com.example.Receiver2"/>
</receiver>
```